# Minimum value of $ f(x) = \frac{2+\sin x}{2+\cos x}$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> Minimum value of $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{2+\sin x}{2+\cos x}$.

**My try:** let $$\displaystyle y = \frac{2+\sin x}{2+\cos x}\Rightarrow 2y+y\cdot \cos x = 2+\sin x$$

So $$y\cdot \cos x-\sin x= 2-2y\;,$$ Now using **Cauchy-Schwarz** Inequality::

$$\displaystyle \left(y^2+(-1)^2\right)\cdot (\cos^2 x+\sin^2 x)\geq (y\cos x-\sin x)^2\Rightarrow (y^2+1)\geq (2-2y)^2$$

So after simplifying $$\displaystyle y^2+1\geq 4+4y^2-8y\Rightarrow 3y^2-8y+3\leq 0$$

So $$\displaystyle 3y^2-8y+3\leq 0 \Rightarrow \frac{1}{2}(4-\sqrt{7})\leq y\leq \frac{1}{3}\left(4+\sqrt{7}\right)$$

But answer given is $\displaystyle = \frac{2}{3}$

So please explain where I am wrong, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HINT:

Let $y=\dfrac{2+\sin x}{2+\cos x}$

Use [Weierstrass substitution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent_half-angle_substitution), to form a Quadratic Equation in $\tan\dfrac x2$

As $\tan\dfrac x2$ is real, the discriminant must be $\ge0$

This should give us the range of $y$

Answer (score 3):

Why not to look as usual at $$f(x)=\frac{2+\sin x}{2+\cos x}$$ $$f'(x)=\frac{2 \sin (x)+2 \cos (x)+1}{(\cos (x)+2)^2}$$ Since the denominator is always defined, the extremum points of the function will be found when $$2 \sin (x)+2 \cos (x)+1=0$$ Using $t=\tan(\frac x2)$, the equation to solve simplifies to $$3+4t-t^2=0$$ which roots are $$t_{\pm}=2\pm \sqrt 7$$ Similarly, the function write $$f(t)=\frac{2 \left(t^2+t+1\right)}{t^2+3}$$ and so $$f(2- \sqrt 7)=\frac{1}{3} \left(4-\sqrt{7}\right)$$ $$f(2+ \sqrt 7)=\frac{1}{3} \left(4+\sqrt{7}\right)$$ and your answer is good (fixing the small typo mentioned by Amzoti).

Answer (score 2):

Well for a start, the "answer given" is wrong,
$$
{2+\sin(3\pi/2)\over 2+\cos(3\pi/2)} = 1/2 < 2/3
$$